# Animation effect between pages change

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to change the animation which is used between pages change.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainApp1 extends Application
{

    final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("1", "Joe", "Pesci"),
        new Person("32", "Rhonda", " Fleming's"),
        new Person("32", "Humphrey", "Bogart"));
    private Pagination pagination;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public int itemsPerPage()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int rowsPerPage()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public VBox createPage(int pageIndex)
    {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int displace = data.size() % rowsPerPage();
        if (displace > 0)
        {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage();
        }
        else
        {
            lastIndex = data.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;

        }

        VBox box = new VBox(5);
        int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();

        for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++)
        {
            TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
            TableColumn numCol = new TableColumn("ID");
            numCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("num"));

            numCol.setMinWidth(20);

            TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
            firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

            firstNameCol.setMinWidth(160);

            TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
            lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

            lastNameCol.setMinWidth(160);

            table.getColumns().addAll(numCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
            if (lastIndex == pageIndex)
            {
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + displace)));
            }
            else
            {
                table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + rowsPerPage())));
            }

            box.getChildren().add(table);
        }
        return box;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
    {

        pagination = new Pagination((data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1), 0);
        //   pagination = new Pagination(20 , 0);
        //pagination.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>()
        {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer pageIndex)
            {
                if (pageIndex > data.size() / rowsPerPage() + 1)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return createPage(pageIndex);
                }
            }
        });

        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pagination, 10.0);
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(pagination);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchor, 400, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table pager");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty num;
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String id, String fName, String lName)
        {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.num = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getNum()
        {
            return num.get();
        }

        public void setNum(String id)
        {
            num.set(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: You have to add table ad opacity zero and then apply animation on it to be shown.

Comment: Could you show us some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that adding animation to the page factory will do the job. I've used the code above and made page slowly appear. See here: http://pastebin.com/5AcCqu95